# Django - SSO with multiple auth sources - LDAP?

Tags: django, authentication, openid, single-sign-on

I have an application running on Django and a bugtracker ([redmine](http://www.redmine.org)).
I'd like to have the same accounts for my users on both applications.
So I decided to install an LDAP on my server and plug my apps on.

In the mean time, in the future I'd like to give my users the ability to attach their accounts with OAuth, OpenID (like Google, Facebook, ...).

Is LDAP still a good idea for this purpose ?

Is it something usual and how easy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a unique LDAP you get resolved the duplicated account problem but you dont get the SSO or SLO functionality. The Ldap plugin of Django and Redmine are easy to configure and are well documented. Same happens with the OpenLdap server.

If you are thinking in the future, I think a nice solution would be to set a SAML enviroment.

- Use  [simplesamlphp to build a IdP](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/trunk/simplesamlphp-idp) and enable the authentication sources that you want: Facebook, Gmail, Ldap, etc
- Use [djangosaml2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2) to add SAML support to django and connect it with the IdP
- Use [this plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_saml_auth) to add SAML support to Redmine and connect it with the IdP

At the end you get a system based on SAML, a  protocol that actually are using Google and other big companies.